# Lua string.match pattern for MSN weatherservice

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I use the [MSN weatherservice](http://weather.service.msn.com). Now I have the following problem with `string.match`. All variables are filled except `sWindRichtung`. It equals `nil`.

```
sHumidity, rest = string.match(rest,"humidity=\"([^\"]+)\"(.*)");
sWind, rest = string.match(rest,"windspeed=\"([^\"]+)\"(.*)");
sWindRichtung, rest = string.match(rest,"winddisplay=\"([^\"]+)\"(.*)");
```

The string to filter is: `humidity="77" winddisplay="11 km/uur N" windspeed="11"`

I think that the character `/` is the problem.

Comment: The problem is that you're parse assumes a certain field order. After parsing `windspeed` nothing comes after it and so `rest` is an empty string.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I found the solution.

Comment: Add your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can parse the string in one go. Try this:

```
s = [[
humidity="77" winddisplay="11 km/uur N" windspeed="11"
]]

for k,v in s:gmatch('(%a+)="(.-)"') do
        print(k,v)
end
```

Of course, you may want to save the values in a table.